# I want to call an Activity on a Fragment

Tags: android, layout

i want to calling activity on Fragment.

what can i do?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webfragment, container, false);
    layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.webFragment);

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), StartActivity.class);
    //intent.setClassName(,)
    startActivity(intent);
    return view;
}
```

i don't want start activity From activity!

Comment: Is you have a fragment being created, and during its creation, you want to start an activity? I'm not sure exactly what is being asked here.

Comment: Do you want to start a fragment instead of an activity? This is confusing